# issue with file path

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What I like to achive is to track the file changes in two directories by using the watchr.

my file structure is the following:

```
/PluginDir
    /classes
        Wrapper.php
    /Tests
        /classes
           WrapperTest.php
           autotest_watchr.rb
```

The contents of the autotest_watchr.rb is the following:

```
watch("../../classes/(.*).php") do |match|
    run_test %{#{match[1]}Test.php}
end

watch(".*Test.php") do |match|
    run_test match[0]
end

def run_test(file)
    clear_console()

    unless File.exists?(file)
        puts "#{file} does not exists"
        return
    end

    puts "Running #{file}"
    results = `phpunit #{file}`
    puts results

    if results.match(/OK/)
        notify "#{file}", "Tests Passed Successfuly", 4500
    elsif results.match(/FAILURES\!/)
        notify_failed file, results
    end
end

def notify_failed cmd, results
    failed_examples =   results.scan(/([0-9]+\))\s+(.*)/)
    notify "#{cmd}", failed_examples[0], 6000
end

def notify title, msg, show_time
    systemMsg   =   "notifu.exe /p \"#{title}\" /m \"#{msg}\" /d #{show_time}"
    systemMsg.gsub('“', "'")
    system systemMsg
end

def clear_console
    system "cls"
end
```

then from folder /PluginDir/Tests/classes/ I execute the following command from cmd:

```
watchr autotest_watchr.rb
```

In this case, the script starts normaly the execution, and when ever I made a modification in my Test files, the console is updated, but when I create a modification in the /PluginDir/classes/*.php files I do not get any update in my console.

Why?

**NOTE:** In first watch("../../classes/...... I have try also the match[0] just in case the regex variable is not correct, but still the script not works

Comment: Ruby to supervise PHP, nice! ;-)

Comment: This is based on : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/automatic-testing-for-tdd-with-php/ :) I am not that kind of Guru !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first search string "../../classes/(.*).php" I think that the "." character is actually a place holder for any single character.
For your usage you probably need to escape it with backslashes, so it would be:

`'\.\./\.\./classes/(.*)\.php'`